# Vue - Pass params from select inside an array.push

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When passing `params` from a select, the usual syntax would be something like this.

```
<v-select
  v-model="item_id"
  items="items"
  item-text="item_name" 
  item-value="id" 
  @change='itemDescription()'
/>

export default {
  data: ()=> ({
    item_id: '',
    items: [],
    itemDescription '',
  }),
  method: {
    itemDescription() {
      axios.get('/api/item', {
        params: { id: this.item_id }
      })
      .then(response => this.itemDescription = response.data )
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem comes when the select is inside an `array.push`. I can't simply pass the value to `this.item_id` since the structure would be `object[0][1]`. Here is an example syntax below.

```
<v-btn @click="addItem()">Add</v-btn>
<template v-for="item in items" :key="item.id>
  <v-select
    v-model="item.item_id"
    items="item_all"
    item-text="item_name" 
    item-value="id" 
    @change='itemDescription()'
  />
</template>

export default {
  data: ()=> ({
    items: [],
    item_all: '',
  }),
  method: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({
      item_id: '',
      description: '',
    }),
    itemDescription() {
      axios.get('/api/item', {
        params: { id: this.items.item_id } // <-- this doesn't work
      })
      .then(response => this.items.description = response.data )
    }
  }
}
```

How do I pass `id` of each row every time I select each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work now. I just used `index`, this was my savior.

Please see code below for those interested

```
<v-btn @click="addItem()">Add</v-btn>
<template v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id>
  <v-select
    v-model="item.item_id"
    items="item_all"
    item-text="item_name" 
    item-value="id" 
    @change='itemDescription(index)'
  />
</template>

export default {
  data: ()=> ({
    items: [],
    item_all: '',
    itemDescription '',
  }),
  method: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({
      item_id: '',
      description: '',
    }),
    itemDescription(index) {
      axios.get('/api/item', {
        params: { id: this.items[index].item_id } // <-- this doesn't work
      })
      .then(response => this.items[index].description = response.data )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'this' in itemDescription method isn't same as 'this' in 'method:'.
so it will not work.

use another variable to keep this, and use it in itemDescription.

```
  method: {
    var that = this;
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({
      item_id: '',
      description: '',
    }),
    itemDescription() {
      axios.get('/api/item', {
        params: { id: that.items.item_id } // 'this' ain't work
      })
      .then(response => this.items.description = response.data )
    }
```